# How to print each list in a multidimensional array python?

Tags: python

I have a large multidimensional array, and I was like to print each list in this array. I have tried to loop through, but it instead prints out each list item of each list separately. I would like the entire list to be printed together. How do I do this? Thankyou.
This is my current attempt:

```
import math
from collections import Counter

with open('OOR LIST VERTICAL.txt') as input_file:
    long_list = [line.strip() for line in input_file]

C = Counter(long_list)
print( [ [k,]*v for k,v in C.items()])

for each in long_list:
    print(each)
```

This is what my multidimensional array looks like:

```
[['2281', '2281', '2281', '2281', '2281', '2281'], ['2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095'], ['2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153', '2153'], ['3207', '3207', '3207'], ['2120', '2120', '2120', '2120', '2120', '2120', '2120', '2120', '2120', '2120'], ['2087', '2087', '2087', '2087', '2087', '2087', '2087', '2087', '2087', '2087', '2087'], ['2270'], ['2126', '2126', '2126', '2126', '2126', '2126', '2126', '2126'], ['2103', '2103', '2103', '2103', '2103', '2103', '2103', '2103', '2103'], ['2100', '2100', '2100', '2100', '2100'], ['2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101', '2101'], ['2112', '2112', '2112', '2112'], ['2011', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2011'], ['2032', '2032', '2032'], ['2234'], ['2223', '2223'], ['2000', '2000'], ['2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107', '2107'], ['2066', '2066', '2066', '2066', '2066', '2066', '2066'], ['2147', '2147', '2147', '2147', '2147', '2147', '2147', '2147', '2147', '2147'], ['2016', '2016', '2016', '2016'], ['2204', '2204', '2204', '2204'], ['2303', '2303', '2303', '2303', '2303'], ['2131', '2131'], ['2050', '2050', '2050', '2050'], ['2121', '2121', '2121', '2121', '2121', '2121', '2121', '2121', '2121', '2121', '2121', '2121', '2121'], ['2070', '2070', '2070', '2070', '2070', '2070', '2070', '2070'], ['2165'], ['2289'], ['2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154', '2154'], ['2102', '2102', '2102', '2102', '2102', '2102', '2102', '2102', '2102', '2102', '2102'], ['2159', '2159', '2159', '2159'], ['2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119', '2119'], ['2151'], ['2096', '2096', '2096', '2096', '2096', '2096', '2096', '2096', '2096', '2096', '2096', '2096', '2096', '2096'], ['2092', '2092'], ['2093', '2093', '2093', '2093', '2093', '2093', '2093', '2093', '2093', '2093', '2093', '2093', '2093', '2093', '2093'], ['2127', '2127', '2127', '2127', '2127'], ['2305', '2305', '2305'], ['2068'], ['2137', '2137', '2137', '2137', '2137'], ['2179'], ['2141', '2141'], ['2076', '2076', '2076', '2076', '2076', '2076', '2076', '2076', '2076', '2076', '2076', '2076', '2076', '2076', '2076', '2076'], ['418683757'], ['2079', '2079', '2079', '2079', '2079', '2079'], ['2322'], ['2913', '2913', '2913', '2913'], ['2538'], ['114'], ['2749', '2749'], ['2200'], ['2565', '2565', '2565', '2565', '2565', '2565', '2565', '2565'], ['2089', '2089', '2089'], ['2035', '2035', '2035', '2035', '2035', '2035', '2035', '2035'], ['2800', '2800'], ['2193', '2193', '2193'], ['2768', '2768'], ['2150'], ['2113', '2113', '2113', '2113'], ['2075', '2075', '2075', '2075', '2075', '2075', '2075', '2075'], ['2046', '2046', '2046', '2046', '2046'], ['2041', '2041', '2041', '2041', '2041', '2041', '2041', '2041', '2041', '2041', '2041', '2041', '2041', '2041', '2041', '2041'], ['2074', '2074', '2074', '2074', '2074', '2074', '2074', '2074', '2074'], ['2148', '2148', '2148', '2148', '2148'], ['2203', '2203', '2203', '2203', '2203'], ['2114', '2114', '2114', '2114', '2114'], ['2122', '2122', '2122', '2122', '2122', '2122', '2122', '2122', '2122', '2122'], ['2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099', '2099'], ['2325', '2325', '2325', '2325'], ['2077', '2077', '2077', '2077', '2077', '2077', '2077', '2077', '2077', '2077', '2077'], ['2582'], ['2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088', '2088'], ['2745', '2745', '2745', '2745'], ['2104', '2104', '2104', '2104', '2104'], ['2069', '2069', '2069', '2069', '2069'], ['2145', '2145', '2145', '2145', '2145'], ['2192', '2192', '2192'], ['2222'], ['2287', '2287', '2287'], ['2155', '2155', '2155', '2155', '2155', '2155', '2155', '2155', '2155', '2155', '2155', '2155', '2155', '2155'], ['2763', '2763', '2763', '2763', '2763', '2763', '2763'], ['2020', '2020', '2020', '2020', '2020'], ['2290', '2290', '2290', '2290'], ['2167', '2167'], ['2040', '2040', '2040'], ['2060', '2060', '2060', '2060', '2060', '2060', '2060', '2060', '2060'], ['2777'], ['2045', '2045'], ['5290', '5290'], ['2027'], ['2097', '2097', '2097', '2097', '2097'], ['2042', '2042', '2042', '2042', '2042'], ['2038', '2038', '2038', '2038'], ['2612'], ['2065', '2065', '2065', '2065', '2065', '2065', '2065', '2065', '2065', '2065', '2065', '2065', '2065', '2065', '2065', '2065'], ['2216'], ['2298', '2298', '2298', '2298', '2298'], ['2166', '2166', '2166'], ['2170', '2170', '2170'], ['2773'], ['2299', '2299'], ['2067', '2067'], ['2023', '2023', '2023', '2023', '2023', '2023'], ['2015'], ['2217', '2217', '2217', '2217'], ['2010'], ['4560', '4560'], ['2269'], ['2094', '2094', '2094', '2094', '2094'], ['2072', '2072', '2072', '2072', '2072', '2072', '2072', '2072', '2072'], ['2029', '2029', '2029'], ['2021', '2021'], ['2090', '2090', '2090', '2090', '2090'], ['2323', '2323', '2323', '2323', '2323', '2323', '2323', '2323', '2323', '2323', '2323', '2323', '2323'], ['2080', '2080', '2080'], ['2307', '2307', '2307', '2307'], ['2285', '2285', '2285', '2285', '2285'], ['2617', '2617'], ['2213', '2213', '2213', '2213'], ['2207', '2207'], ['2224'], ['2059'], ['2106', '2106', '2106', '2106', '2106', '2106', '2106', '2106', '2106', '2106', '2106'], ['2455'], ['2073', '2073', '2073', '2073', '2073', '2073', '2073', '2073'], ['2195'], ['1355'], ['2019', '2019', '2019'], ['2765', '2765', '2765', '2765', '2765', '2765', '2765', '2765', '2765'], ['2025'], ['2108', '2108'], ['2228'], ['2201'], ['2614'], ['2082', '2082', '2082', '2082', '2082', '2082', '2082', '2082', '2082'], ['2780'], ['2048', '2048', '2048'], ['2218', '2218'], ['2360', '2360', '2360', '2360'], ['2760', '2760', '2760'], ['2136', '2136', '2136'], ['94661', '94661', '94661'], ['2283', '2283', '2283', '2283', '2283', '2283', '2283', '2283', '2283', '2283'], ['2085', '2085'], ['2063', '2063', '2063', '2063'], ['2280', '2280', '2280', '2280', '2280', '2280', '2280', '2280', '2280', '2280', '2280'], ['2530', '2530'], ['2430'], ['2517'], ['3402'], ['2786', '2786'], ['2036'], ['2146', '2146'], ['2564', '2564', '2564', '2564'], ['2194'], ['2163'], ['2110'], ['2017', '2017'], ['2609'], ['2158', '2158', '2158', '2158'], ['2284', '2284'], ['2320'], ['2579'], ['2570'], ['2233', '2233'], ['2105'], ['3173'], ['2774'], ['2318'], ['2156', '2156', '2156', '2156'], ['2456', '2456', '2456', '2456'], ['2034'], ['2560'], ['2117', '2117'], ['2446', '2446'], ['2850'], ['2133', '2133'], ['2782'], ['2188'], ['2125'], ['2574', '2574'], ['2190'], ['2140', '2140'], ['2086', '2086', '2086', '2086'], ['2770', '2770', '2770'], ['2026', '2026', '2026'], ['2037', '2037', '2037'], ['2031'], ['2759', '2759', '2759'], ['2152', '2152'], ['2775'], ['76262', '76262'], ['2157'], ['2444', '2444'], ['2445'], ['2176', '2176'], ['2199', '2199', '2199'], ['2567'], ['2282', '2282', '2282', '2282', '2282'], ['2132', '2132'], ['2084', '2084'], ['2632', '2632'], ['2576'], ['2821'], ['2227', '2227', '2227'], ['2756', '2756'], ['2477'], ['2291', '2291'], ['2009', '2009'], ['4053', '4053'], ['2340'], ['2047'], ['2220', '2220', '2220'], ['2370'], ['2142'], ['3926'], ['3136', '3136']]
```

I would like it to print out like this:

```
['2281', '2281', '2281', '2281', '2281', '2281']

['2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095', '2095']
```

etc.

Comment: You should show your current attempt.

Comment: current attempt has been added.

Comment: Can you add an example desired output. Your explanation is a little hard to follow.

Comment: You should add example data too, e.g. an example of what long_list looks like. Or at least what the data in the file looks like.  Ideally, we should be able to (try to) run your example code, and that can't be done right now.

Comment: I guess you want to have a list with lines of text  long_list  = [ [line1],[line2],....] but there is no read statement. Gives your output samples too,

Comment: Do you want to print every entry in the counter as a separate list  ?

Comment: yes exactly what I would like to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make use of the counter.items() to achieve it without the ','.

```
for item,count in C.items():
    print( [item]*count )
```